# How to sort the database columns in Report Builder Query Designer?

Tags: visual-studio, query-builder, reportbuilder

We are trying to switch from Crystal Reports to SSRS, and in Report Builder, the "Query Builder" is for some reason displaying the database columns in seemingly random order (see image).

This didn't happen in Crystal Reports at all (they were in alphabetical order), but I can't find any way to sort them.

These are views, not tables, in case that somehow makes a difference - and the database is hosted by a third party, so database-side solutions aren't an option either.

[image]

I tried Visual Studio instead of report builder, but had the exact same issue - nothing I could find in datasource options, any right click menus, keyboard shortcuts, etc.

Comment: This is the order of the columns in the view, the only way to change this would be to edit the view itself. To be honest, in the 20 years I've been working with SSRS, it's never been an issue, although I tend to write dataset queries by hand and never use the designer as it's pretty limited

Comment: I figured as much, but thanks for the confirmation! I'll probably just make a reference list to search through for the column names, and then do it by hand as well.